# Maven - reduce time taken for remote repository access

Tags: maven, hibernate-spatial

My project uses hibernate-spatial package. Following is the entry from pom.xml file

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>Hibernate Spatial repo</id>
        <url>http://www.hibernatespatial.org/repository</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
    <version>4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

When I do `mvn clean install`, maven tries to access the remote repository which doesn't exist anymore. Following is the message I see in the console log.

> Downloading: http://www.hibernatespatial.org/repository/_project
>   _related_info/maven-metadata.xml Nov 24, 2016 9:34:20 AM
>   org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RetryExec
>   execute INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when
>   processing request to {}->http://www.hibernatespatial.org:80:
>   Operation timed out Nov 24, 2016 9:34:20 AM
>   org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RetryExec
>   execute INFO: Retrying request to
>   {}->http://www.hibernatespatial.org:80 Nov 24, 2016 9:35:23 AM
>   org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RetryExec
>   execute INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when
>   processing request to {}->http://www.hibernatespatial.org:80:
>   Operation timed out Nov 24, 2016 9:35:23 AM
>   org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RetryExec
>   execute INFO: Retrying request to
>   {}->http://www.hibernatespatial.org:80 [WARNING] Could not transfer
>   metadata _project_related_info/maven-metadata.xml from/to Hibernate
>   Spatial repo (http://www.hibernatespatial.org/repository): Connect to
>   www.hibernatespatial.org:80 [www.hibernatespatial.org/62.213.201.148]
>   failed: Operation timed out

Actually the package is available inside my `~/.m2/repository` folder. So after multiple timeouts maven looks in the local repository, finds it there and build succeeds. How can I reduce the time taken for remote repository checking.

I try to put the following into my `~/.m2/settings.xml` file but it didn't help.

```
<server>
  <id>central</id>
  <configuration>
    <httpConfiguration>
      <all>
        <connectionTimeout>5000</connectionTimeout>
        <readTimeout>5000</readTimeout>
      </all>
    </httpConfiguration>
  </configuration>
</server>
```

Comment: this should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141211/maven-without-remote-repository

Comment: I suggest you get artifactory and make your work easy :)

Comment: If you use a release (non-SNAPSHOT) version, Maven always draws the artifact from the local repository. If it is not there, it is downloaded from the remote repository. Maybe the metadata in your local repository is broken. Try to delete the metadata entries from the relevant directories in the local repository.

Answer (score 0):

Running maven in offline mode helped me to solve the issue

```
mvn -o clean install
```